# Bodmer / TFT_eSPI touchscreen button "Destroy comand"

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, touchscreen, adafruit, arduino-esp32

This question is specific to a library ,[Bodmer's Tft_eSPI](https://github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI)
The author mentioned that he got the button code from [Adafruit GFX Library](http://adafruit.github.io/Adafruit-GFX-Library/html/index.html), so they should be similar.

My problem is a simple one: I want to make a simple button menu. I have figured out how to create a button and display a button, using [this keypad example](https://github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI/blob/master/examples/320%20x%20240/Keypad_240x320/Keypad_240x320.ino)

To init a button, I am using this code:

`key[0].initButton(&tft, (KEY_X + 70) + 0 * (KEY_W + KEY_SPACING_X), KEY_Y + 0 * (KEY_H + KEY_SPACING_Y), // x, y, w, h, outline, fill, text KEY_W, KEY_H, TFT_WHITE, Main_Menu_Buttton_Colours[0], TFT_WHITE, Main_Menu_Buttton_Labels[0], KEY_TEXTSIZE);`

And then, to display the button, I am using this command `key[0].drawButton();`

This works perfectly.
The problem comes when I want to display another page.
Using `tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);` or even `tft.init();` still displays the buttons under a layer and they work and even show when I press that area. I want to mention that I stop calling the functions that I mentioned in the loop.
My question is  : How do I get read of the buttons in order to create other ones?